# Changing routers messed up my web server on my virtual PC

Tags: networking, router

I changed my router and now my virtual PC HTTP web server is not working.  Any ideas?

I added the entry of this virtual PC to my virtual servers on my new router to be an HTTP server.  Not sure what else I'm missing?

Maybe I need to clear cache or something? I can't even ping my virtual PC anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the new router has either:

a. renumbered your internal network's IP addresses; or,

b. doesn't have TCP port forwarding (or a DMZ) set up like the previous one did.

Comment: a. it did renumber the internal network, but everything is dhcp
b. on my new router it says Block ICMP ping (does that mean i can't ping my internal network)

Comment: @rod:  Usually it means that ICMP requests for "ping" from hosts on the public side will be ignored.  You should still be able to use ping internally.

Comment: Just had to toggle my Windows FireWall on and off and it started working again. Is that strange?

Comment: @rod:  Yes and no.  Unfortunately the Windows Firewall does interfere with a lot programs, and customizations is often required to make it work properly.  The best approach to use is to create an exception for the specific application or TCP/UDP port numbers (and document what it's used for in the comments box that Windows provides when you do this).